# Saving and Loading Trained Stanford classifier in java

Tags: java, twitter, stanford-nlp, text-classification, maxent

I have a dataset of 1 million labelled sentences and using it for finding sentiment through Maximum Entropy. I am using Stanford Classifier for the same:-

```
public class MaximumEntropy {

static ColumnDataClassifier cdc;

public static float calMaxEntropySentiment(String text) {
    initializeProperties();
    float sentiment = (getMaxEntropySentiment(text));
    return sentiment;
}

public static void initializeProperties() {
    cdc = new ColumnDataClassifier(
            "\\stanford-classifier-2016-10-31\\properties.prop");
}

public static int getMaxEntropySentiment(String tweet) {

    String filteredTweet = TwitterUtils.filterTweet(tweet);
    System.out.println("Reading training file");
    Classifier<String, String> cl = cdc.makeClassifier(cdc.readTrainingExamples(
            "\\stanford-classifier-2016-10-31\\labelled_sentences.txt"));

    Datum<String, String> d = cdc.makeDatumFromLine(filteredTweet);
    System.out.println(filteredTweet + "  ==>  " + cl.classOf(d) + " " + cl.scoresOf(d));
    // System.out.println("Class score is: " +
    // cl.scoresOf(d).getCount(cl.classOf(d)));
    if (cl.classOf(d) == "0") {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 4;
    }
}
}
```

My data is labelled 0 or 1. Now for each tweet the whole dataset is being read and it is taking a lot of time considering the size of dataset.
My query is that is there any way to first train the classifier and then load it when a tweet's sentiment is to be found. I think this approach will take less time. Correct me if I am wrong. 
The following link provides this but there is nothing for JAVA API.
[Saving and Loading Classifier](https://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier#Saving_and_loading_this_classifier)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; the easiest way to do this is using Java's default serialization mechanism to serialize a classifier. A useful helper here is the `IOUtils` class:

```
IOUtils.writeObjectToFile(classifier, "/path/to/file");
```

To read the classifier:

```
Classifier<String, String> cl = IOUtils.readObjectFromFile(new File("/path/to/file");
```